# Can't run multiple batch files sequentially from master batch file in Win7

Tags: batch-file

I have a bunch of batch files that each start a bunch of executables to run concurrently.  Each batch file starts 30 executables.  When those 30 are done, I want the next batch of executables to run, again 30 at a time.  The .exe's are called using the "start" command in the batch files and they work just fine - I can run the individual batch files for each group of 30 exe's  and they run concurrently like they should.

I have created a "master" batch file that calls each sub-batch file but I can't figure out how to get it to run the sub-batch files in sequence, waiting for one to finish before starting the next.

If the master batch file is like this:

```
Batch1.bat
Batch2.bat
Batch3.bat
```

then only the first batch file is called - the others are never called.

If the master batch file is like this:

```
call Batch1.bat
call Batch2.bat
call Batch3.bat
```

then all of the sub-batch files start running at the same time and I get hundreds of executables trying to start up at the same time.

How do I make the master batch file call the first batch file, wait for it to finish, then call the next, wait for it to finish, then call the next, etc?

Thanks in advance,

rgames

Comment: The problem is not that the catch files are running in parallel. It is that you are using "start" to run the exes. "start" does not wait for the program to exit. Remove the "start" keyword.

Comment: I want to run all 30 exe's in each batch file at the same time, so I need to use "start".  If I don't use "start" then the 30 exe's don't run concurrently.  I want the batch files to run conescutively but I want the exe's within each batch file to run concurrently.

Comment: how about starting your exes with `start "Myexe one" one.exe` `start "Myexe two" two.exe`etc.? You can then check if some of them are still  running with `tasklist |find "Myexe"`

Comment: Then you are getting exactly what you want. The first batch file launches 30 programs simultaneously without waiting. Then the second batch file launches another 30 programs simultaneously without waiting, for a total of 60. Then the third batch file launches another 30, for a total of 90.

Comment: yes - that's what the `tasklist` for: check if all of the `exe` are finished. (of course you will have to embed it to a loop: `all of them gone? yes -> exit, else wait again`)

Comment: Alas - I am not getting what I want!  See post below.  The problem is that the second batch file never launches.  The command window for the first one is just sitting there - it never closes, so the second never starts.  An if if I use the "EXIT" command then the master batch file puts a prompt saying "Terminate Batch y/n?" and it just sits there, defeating the purpose of trying to run the batch file!  I can't believe this is so hard...!

Comment: Again, just to be clear, the individual sub-batch files (batch1.bat, batch2.bat, etc) work fine - the 30 exe's in each one start up and run concurrently like I want them to.  The problem is I can't figure out a way to call those batch files from a MASTER batch file so that they run consecutively.  I want the .exe's in batch1.bat, batch2.bat, etc. to run CONCURRENTLY (which they do).  I want batch1.bat, batch2.bat, etc to be called from a MASTER batch file that runs them CONSECUTIVELY.  Every solution described here so far either runs the batch files all at once or it stops after the first one.

Answer (score 2):

When starting another batch CALL will start it in the same window and the called batch has access to the same variable context. So it can also change variables which affects the caller.

Using wait in your batch file to call the executable will wait for them to exit before.

```
START /WAIT  batch1.bat
START /WAIT batch2.bat
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't appear to work.  It still stops after Batch1.bat.  There are, however, two more cmd.exe windows open just sitting there.  One has the command line with "START /WAIT Batch1.bat" and the other seems to show all the commands from Batch1.bat.  Do I need to add some kind of "return" statement from the sub-batch files?  The exit command doesn't work.

Comment: It works by waiting for batch1.bat to exit and then batch2.bat will run, as you asked.  The reason why your batch1.bat is not exiting is what you have to find.  You can also use `start "" /w /b batch1.bat` which will wait and run it in the same cmd window.  The `""` are used to prevent a quoted path in the command from causing an issue.

Comment: If I use 'start "" /w /b batch1.bat' etc. in the master batch file then it runs all the batch files at once and all the executables from all the batches run at the same time.  Indeed - it appears that batch1.bat never exits - the window for that batch file just sits there with a command prompt, waiting for something to happen.  How do I tell batch1.bat to close its window?  I guess that's why the second window is sitting there - it's the window for the master batch file waiting for the batch1.bat window to close.  My problem isn't solved but I am learning somthing...!  Any other ideas?

Comment: Include the directory from where your batch file can be found. e.g: `call "C:\Batch1.bat"`, call `"C:\Batch2.bat"` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me. I think there is a misunderstanding here. If your master Batch file is this:

```
call Batch1.bat
call Batch2.bat
call Batch3.bat
```

then the Batch2.bat is called after Batch1.bat ends, and so on. You may do a small test to confirm this. On the other side, is possible that each BatchN.bat program uses *the same* variables? If so, then the last values left from Batch1.bat may interfere with Batch2.bat, and so on. In this case, you must add a `Setlocal` command at beginning of each Batch file.

Comment: Each sub-batch file (batch1.bat, batch2.dat, etc) has 'set tempDir=%CD%' as the first line.  It does that because it changes directory off the current root, starts the .exe in that directory, then changes back to the root directory so it can change to the next directory and start the next .exe.  I've tried it both with and without setlocal and it makes no difference.  I wouldn't expect it to - the variable being set should always be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had to run a data export program for several files. My solution:

MasterBatch.bat:

```
@echo off
start /w batch1.bat
start /w batch2.bat
```

Batch1.bat

```
@echo off
cmd /c "c: & cd Program Files (x86)/PATH & targetProgram.exe -parametersToExportVideo1"
EXIT
```

Batch2.bat

```
@echo off
cmd /c "c: & cd Program Files (x86)/PATH & targetProgram.exe -parametersToExportVideo2"
EXIT
```

It may be adapted to run programs other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a signaling mechanism to aware EXE completation.

I would create a third level batch to run each EXE, creating a temp file before executing EXE and deleting it after.

In sub-batch I would wait until there were no more temp files.

So, initial batch:

```
call Batch1.bat
call Batch2.bat
call Batch3.bat
```

Sub-batch:

```
Set Index=0
Call :Exec exefile1 args ...
Call :Exec exefile2 args ...
...
:WaitAll
If Exist %Temp%\RUNNING_EXE.*.TMP GoTo :WaitAll
GoTo :EOF

:Exec
Set /A Index+=1
Echo %Index% > %Temp%\RUNNING_EXE.%Index%.TMP
Start Batch_3rd.BAT %*
GoTo :EOF
```

Finally, 3rd level batch, Batch_3rd.BAT:

```
%*
Del %Temp%\RUNNING_EXE.%Index%.TMP
```

`%*` are arguments passed from sub-batch (exe+arguments), `%Index%` is correct as `start` copies environment from sub-batch upon creation, and sub-batch don't change this copy.
One final note: you can probably merge all batches into a single batch file, calling it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1)
I have four batch files:
Parent.bat and Batch1.bat, Batch2.bat, Batch3.bat

2)
Parent.bat contains the below lines (take a close note):

call Batch1.bat > result1.log

call Batch2.bat > result2.log

call Batch3.bat > result3.log

3)
Make sure "into the end of Each Child batch file", you have an echo statement.
After this echo statement there shouldn't be any code...

Say content of Batch1.bat file is:

echo begin

robocopy "C:\Users\DD\Documents\A" "C:\Users\DD\Documents\B"

echo end

echo this_is_the_last_line

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, i will use simple sub-batches like (all of them are the same)

```dos
@echo off
    for /l %%a in (1 1 5) do start "" notepad.exe
```

And a master batch file

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "flagFile=%temp%\%random%%random%%random%.tmp"

    for %%a in ( "batch1.cmd" "batch2.cmd" "batch3.cmd" ) do (
        call :startBatch %%a "%flagFile%"
    )

:retryClean
    echo %time% waiting for last batch to end
    2>nul ( 9>"%flagFile%" break ) || ( >nul timeout 5 & goto :retryClean )
    del /q "%flagFile%"

    echo DONE
    pause
    goto :eof

:startBatch batchFile flagFile
    echo %time% waiting to start "%~1"
    2>nul ( 9>"%~2" call "%~1" ) || ( >nul timeout 5 & goto :startBatch )
    echo %time% [ "%~1" ] STARTED
    goto :eof
```

This code starts each of the sub-batches with an active redirection (user available stream 9 is used) to a temporary flag file. This will lock the flag file until all the processes started from sub-batches have ended as the redirection is inherited during the process creation.

All we have to do is to keep trying start the next batch file with the same redirection:

- If the file is still locked (processes are running), the batch file can not be started, wait 5 seconds and retry again
- If the file is not locked, the redirection can be created and the next batch file is started.